# Post content being duplicated by the_content();

Tags: posts, wp-query, the-content

I have a query that runs through a set of posts with the post type `location`. It returns them broken down by a custom field value (in this case, the state in which the location is located). For some reason, just one post is being duplicated on the page. When I use `the_content` or `apply_filters('the_content', $content);`, it duplicates that one post. When I use `get_the_content`, it returns the post content normally, but it doesn't have the formatting that I need. What in my code could be causing this?

```
$state_posts = array();

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $state = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'state', true);
    $state_posts[$state][] = $post;
}

foreach ($state_posts as $state_post => $state_title) {
?>
<h1 class="state-name"><?php echo esc_html($state_post); ?></h1>
<?php
foreach ($state_title as $listing) {
    setup_postdata($listing);
    $post_id = $listing->ID;
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));
    $distance = facetwp_get_distance($post_id);
    $distance = (false !== $distance) ? round($distance, 1) . ' miles away' : '';
    $coords = get_post_meta($post_id, 'location', true);
?>
<div class="post-item" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" data-latitude="<?php echo $coords['lat']; ?>" data-longitude="<?php echo $coords['lng']; ?>" data-distance="<?php echo $distance; ?>">
  <div class="post-item-content">
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
    <div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
   }
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Here is the page in question: https://dare2sharelive.org/locations/?fwp_states=missouri

And yes, I have checked if anything is odd about the two posts in particular, and they're formatted exactly the same as all the other posts.

Edit: here's the query just in case something in there is the issue.

```
<?php
return array(
    'post_type' => 'location',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'state',
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value' => 'ASC',
        'title' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Is it possible the one that's duplicating itself has a revision, and none of the other posts do? You might check your initial query and make sure it's searching for `'post-status' => 'publish'` to rule it out.

Comment: I double checked and I'm definitely querying for published posts. I'll post the full query in an edit as well.

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $state_posts )` after the while loop. Does it contain the expected results?

Comment: Yes, it shows exactly what it should. the `post_content` matches what is expected. But when I use `the_content` or `apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id))` as shown above, it changes for just the one post.

Comment: I'd avoid using the variable named `$post` in the while loop; rename it to something unique like `$state_post`. Also add `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `while` loop.

Comment: Renaming that variable ended up just making one post repeat four times. However, when I replaced `echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id))` with `echo wpautop( get_the_content() )`, it worked.

Comment: I should have worded that differently. Instead of `$state_posts[$state][] = $post;` I'd do `$state_posts[$state][] = $query->post;`

Comment: Oh, my bad. Well that didn't change anything, either. I'll still leave that change since it's a better practice, though.

Comment: Whenever I visit the URL I don't see any repeated posts/content. Is this issue resolved?

Comment: I've found a workaround, though the problem has not been resolved. I'm going to post the workaround as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is still present, but I've found a workaround for now. When I replaced `echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id))` with `echo wpautop( get_the_content() )`, it worked. I also stopped using the variable $post since I wasn't accessing the global post variable.

So that makes my code look like so:

```
$state_posts = array();

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $state = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'state', true);
    // Changed code here
    $state_posts[$state][] = $query->post;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

foreach ($state_posts as $state_post => $state_title) {
?>
<h1 class="state-name"><?php echo esc_html($state_post); ?></h1>
<?php
foreach ($state_title as $listing) {
    setup_postdata($listing);
    $post_id = $listing->ID;
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $distance = facetwp_get_distance($post_id);
    $distance = (false !== $distance) ? round($distance, 1) . ' miles away' : '';
    $coords = get_post_meta($post_id, 'location', true);
?>
<div class="post-item" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" data-latitude="<?php echo $coords['lat']; ?>" data-longitude="<?php echo $coords['lng']; ?>" data-distance="<?php echo $distance; ?>">
  <div class="post-item-content">
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
    // Changed code here
    <div><?php echo wpautop( get_the_content() ); ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
   }
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

If anyone has any insight into why the problem occurred, that would be awesome. But either way, the posts are loading correctly with this different code. Thanks to everyone who gave input!