# the_content() not displaying description correctly

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to display a description of a WooCommerce single product, but the instead of displaying the correct description, the loop starts over again displaying the image, price, add to cart etc.

I've tried to find the answer for long time with no avail.
I have used the WooCommerce template scripts and edit them; `the_excerpt()` will work but not `the_content(`).

This is the template file I am currently using: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php

`the_content()` is now the problem. Could it be my query or something? I have different way to query my products from **index.php**, but the **archive-product.php** is having the same as WooCommerce query has. Could this be the cause, even if it's in the **single-product.php** the problem?

I use this for the **front-page.php**:s product loop:

```
<div class="col-9 main-products">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[products paginate="true" limit="30" orderby="popularity"]'); ?>
</div>
```

**content-single-product.php**, **archive-product.php** and **single-product.php** are the same as the WooCommerce template has.

It should display the description instead of looping over again. There are no error messages.

I've also used a different theme and the products display correctly, so the problem isn't in any plugins I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo wpautop(get_the_content());
```

This code fixed the problem! I found out the solution from here: [Post content being duplicated by the_content();](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298383/post-content-being-duplicated-by-the-content) by KreigD's answer.